# Need to bootload multiple times when using Nick Gammons program

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I have been facing this issue with Nick Gammon's Arduino boot loader that every time I bootload and write a program via  Rx-Tx to an Atmega 2560 but if I want to re write another program the IDE shows an error and the whole process has to be repeated, is this normal behaviour?

Its sort of an issue as I am programming an LCD and need to make lots of small changes.

TIA.